# shop page with all categories with paginate

Tags: categories

I am very new in wordpress theme development.
how can i make page template for my store page where my all categories listed with 6 to 10 latest post with that category and category name has a link to category page `category.php`
**for example:**

in store page

**category 1**

1. first item with this category
2. second item with this category
3. third item with this category
4. forth item with this category

**category 2**

1. first item with this category
2. second item with this category
3. third item with this category
4. forth item with this category

**category 3**

1. first item with this category
2. second item with this category
3. third item with this category
4. forth item with this category

**and so on**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is petty straightforward solution

first get your all categories list by help of `get_categories()` function and loop though
and find the post relative with that.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories(); return all categories
    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $query = new WP_query(['cat'=>$cat->term_id, 'postes_per_page'=> 10]);
        if( $query->have_postes() ){
            echo $cate-name; // this this category name
            while( $query -> have_postes() ) {
               // show your all post relavent to this category..
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: As I stated in the other answer, this is really expensive and not good for performance

Answer (score 1):

You first need to grab a list of your categories, and they run a wordpress query for each category.

```
$cats = get_categories(); //Get all the categories
foreach ($cats as $cat) : //Loop through all the categories
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, //limit it to 5 posts per category
        'cat' => $cat->term_id, //Get posts for this specific category in the loop
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>
        <ul>
        <?php while $query->have_posts()) : the_post(); //loop through the posts in this category ?>    
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query; //reset the query ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you want to restricted the categories you are looping through to a specific post type or something else, you can pass parameters to the get_categories method. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) for more details on that

This code would replace the loop in your categories.php template or where ever else you want to list them.

Comment: This is really expensive. I have done a couple of posts regarding this issue where you can use transients and usort in order to reorder posts according to term where you run **one** query only ;-)

Comment: And to the guy with the accepted answer: if you gonna copy my answer and get it accepted, at least get your PHP syntax right.